# Calculate the standard deviation of a moving windows using 2d convolution

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, pytorch

I am doing a image processing project.
I want to calculate the standard deviation of a silding window using 2d convolution. I can now calculate the mean, but I cannot find a way to calculate the standard deviation. Here is my code:

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)
torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')
testvideo=cv2.VideoCapture ("test.mp4")
if testvideo.isOpened():
    ret, frame = testvideo.read()
    if ret == True:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        imgarr=np.asarray(gray)
        #plt.imshow(imgarr,cmap="gray")
        imgtensor=torch.from_numpy(imgarr).float().to(device).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
        print(imgtensor.device)
        #print(intensity.device)
        MeanConv=torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 1, kernel_size=100)
        kernel=(torch.ones(100,100)/10000).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
        MeanConv.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(kernel)
        print(kernel)
        intensity=MeanConv(imgtensor)
        plt.imshow(intensity.squeeze(0).squeeze(0).detach().cpu().numpy(),cmap="gray")
        #for i in range(714):
            #for j in range(714):
                #intensity[i,j]=torch.mean(imgtensor[i:i+7,j:j+7])
                #sd[i,j]=torch.std(imgtensor[i:i+7,j:j+7])
        #x=(sd/intensity).cpu()
        #plt.imshow(x.numpy(),cmap="gray")
testvideo.release()
```

Comment: SD = Standard Deviation? Also, please create a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), helps us run the code when we help you troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: The standard deviation is not a linear operation, and cannot be implemented with a convolution.

Comment: @Torxed, I just edited it. SD is the standard deviation.

Comment: Looks better, might have s crack at it in the morning :)

Comment: @bnaecker, Is there any other ways to calculate it instead using a loop to calculate it one by one. I tried using a loop(which I've commented out in the code), and it is very time-consuming.

Comment: @Torxed, thx to you. You can test it with a whatever video file under the same fold. it will read the first frame and do a 2d convolution

Comment: @ZihaoZou You could create a reshaped array, with each local region on the second axis, and then compute the standard deviation along that axis.

Comment: This simply cannot be done. A convolution is a linear operator, the standard deviation is not. But you can import a library that has this implemented. Plenty of those around.

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be somehow like this:

1. mean (img) using convolution.
2. Subtract from the original image of p. 1
3. Calculate the square of each element.
4. By convolution we find the average, p. 3
5. Calculates the square root of the elements of p. 4

Comment: While you can do this, you have to be careful because of [Catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation).
Calculating the sum of squares can lead to large numbers.

Comment: The mean obtained from the convolution does not equal to μ that is required to be subtracted from the sample.